# In SQL Server, create row number column

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table like below.

| ContactID | FaaliyetTipi | Sonuc | Yil |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | Klavye | 1999 |
| 10 | 2 | Klavye | 1999 |
| 10 | 4 | Klavye | 1999 |
| 10 | 5 | Mouse | 1999 |
| 100 | 6 | Mouse | 1999 |
| 100 | 7 | Klavye | 1999 |
| 100 | 7 | Mouse | 2000 |
| 100 | 9 | Mouse | 1999 |
| 100 | 10 | Mouse | 1999 |

What I want to do in SQL is:

If the values ​​in the "ContactID" and "FaaliyetTipi" columns are equal and the values ​​in the "Sonuc" column are different from each other, I want to subtract the smaller value (row) in the "Yil" column from the data. All remaining rows should remain. I tried `Row_Number` for this but I couldn't get it right. Can you help me?

For example, if we can create a conditional column like the one below, I can write the Where Row_Number = 1 condition and get the result I want.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: If you provide your sample data as DDL+DML you'd make it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: Can multiple rows have the same Sonuc?

Answer (score 0):

My first answer:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 
    t1.ContactID, 
    t1.FaaliyetTipi, 
    t1.Sonuc, 
    t1.Yil,
    t2.Sonuc AS Sonuc2,
    t2.Yil AS Yil2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ContactID, t1.FaaliyetTipi ORDER BY t1.Yil) AS RowNum
  FROM table_name t1
  JOIN table_name t2 
    ON t1.ContactID = t2.ContactID 
    AND t1.FaaliyetTipi = t2.FaaliyetTipi 
    AND t1.Sonuc != t2.Sonuc 
    AND t1.Yil != t2.Yil
    AND t1.Yil > t2.Yil
)
SELECT 
  ContactID, 
  FaaliyetTipi, 
  Sonuc, 
  Yil, 
  CASE 
    WHEN Yil - Yil2 > 0 THEN Yil - Yil2 
    ELSE Yil2 - Yil 
  END AS Difference
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

Then, I changed code:

```
SELECT 
  ContactID, 
  FaaliyetTipi, 
  Sonuc, 
  Yil, 
  MIN(Yil) OVER (PARTITION BY ContactID, FaaliyetTipi) - Yil AS Difference
FROM your_table
WHERE (ContactID, FaaliyetTipi) IN (
  SELECT ContactID, FaaliyetTipi
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY ContactID, FaaliyetTipi
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Sonuc) > 1
)
```

Because, we don't actually need a self-join or `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: A good answer contains an explanation of how it works to assist the OP with their understanding.

Comment: Yeah not sure why you need a self-join *and* a row number?

Comment: @DaleK You are correct. After taking a second look at the question, I realized that a self-join and `ROW_NUMBER()` are not necessary. I'll edit to do simpler code that achieves the same result.

Answer (score 0):

`row_number()` can do the trick.

We add row_number grouping by `ContactID, FaaliyetTipi` and ordering by `Yil`, then we will take all records except rn = 2 which will be the record with the biggest Yil.

```
with cte as (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by ContactID, FaaliyetTipi order by Yil) as rn
  from mytable
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ld8SoIhm)